# Is there a way to get a list of citations for a web page URL?

Tags: publications, citations, conference, arxiv

Sites like Google Scholar track citations to academic articles, however it doesn't do the same for web page URLs. Academic text often cites web pages using their URLs, for e.g., links to GitHub repos, blog posts, even stackoverflow posts.
Is there a way I could find a list of academic articles citing any particular URL?

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11192-021-04082-y) (Enrique Orduña-Malea & Rodrigo Costas. Link-based approach to study scientific software usage: the case of VOSviewer, 2021) deals with your exact question.

The approach is fairly straightforward: just search in GS for the relevant URL substring.